# Use relplot to plot a pandas dataframe leading to error

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, relplot

I want to plot the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Description': {0: 'Growing degree days (sum of Tmean > 4 C)', 1: 'Maximum number of consecutive frost days (Tmin < 0 C)', 2: 'Number of Frost Days (Tmin < 0C)', 3: 'Heating degree days (sum of Tmean < 17 C)', 4: 'Number of sharp Ice Days (Tmax < 0C)', 5: 'Cold-spell duration index', 6: 'Percentage of days when Tmean < 10th percentile', 7: 'Percentage of days when Tmin < 10th percentile', 8: 'Minimum daily maximum temperature', 9: 'Minimum daily minimum temperature'},
        'CEI': {0: 960.5901447, 1: 3.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 307.55743, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 8.0, 7: 7.0, 8: 7.897848629, 9: -3.803963957},
        'Country': {0: 'Argentina', 1: 'Argentina', 2: 'Argentina', 3: 'Argentina', 4: 'Argentina', 5: 'Argentina', 6: 'Argentina', 7: 'Argentina', 8: 'Argentina', 9: 'Argentina'}, 'Region': {0: 'Buenos Aires', 1: 'Buenos Aires', 2: 'Buenos Aires', 3: 'Buenos Aires', 4: 'Buenos Aires', 5: 'Buenos Aires', 6: 'Buenos Aires', 7: 'Buenos Aires', 8: 'Buenos Aires', 9: 'Buenos Aires'},
        'Area': {0: 7107272, 1: 7107272, 2: 7107272, 3: 7107272, 4: 7107272, 5: 7107272, 6: 7107272, 7: 7107272, 8: 7107272, 9: 7107272},
        'Crop': {0: 'Maize', 1: 'Maize', 2: 'Maize', 3: 'Maize', 4: 'Maize', 5: 'Maize', 6: 'Maize', 7: 'Maize', 8: 'Maize', 9: 'Maize'},
        'Season': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1},
        'Method': {0: 'phenological_stages', 1: 'phenological_stages', 2: 'phenological_stages', 3: 'phenological_stages', 4: 'phenological_stages', 5: 'phenological_stages', 6: 'phenological_stages', 7: 'phenological_stages', 8: 'phenological_stages', 9: 'phenological_stages'},
        'Stage': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1},
        'Harvest Year': {0: 2020, 1: 2020, 2: 2020, 3: 2020, 4: 2020, 5: 2020, 6: 2020, 7: 2020, 8: 2020, 9: 2020},
        'Index': {0: 'GD4', 1: 'CFD', 2: 'FD', 3: 'HD17', 4: 'ID', 5: 'CSDI', 6: 'TG10p', 7: 'TN10p', 8: 'TXn', 9: 'TNn'},
        'Type': {0: 'Cold', 1: 'Cold', 2: 'Cold', 3: 'Cold', 4: 'Cold', 5: 'Cold', 6: 'Cold', 7: 'Cold', 8: 'Cold', 9: 'Cold'},
        'percentiles': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: 10.0, 6: 10.0, 7: 10.0, 8: np.nan, 9: np.nan},
        'Z-Score CEI': {0: 0.095693962, 1: 0.875995674, 2: -0.06780635, 3: 0.218503017, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: -0.230243454, 7: -0.42505904, 8: -1.87248784, 9: -1.119380721},
        'Category CEI': {0: 'Average', 1: 'Good', 2: 'Average', 3: 'Average', 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: 'Average', 7: 'Average', 8: 'Failure', 9: 'Poor'},
        'Area (ha)': {0: 2472520, 1: 2472520, 2: 2472520, 3: 2472520, 4: 2472520, 5: 2472520, 6: 2472520, 7: 2472520, 8: 2472520, 9: 2472520},
        'Production (tn)': {0: 15595357, 1: 15595357, 2: 15595357, 3: 15595357, 4: 15595357, 5: 15595357, 6: 15595357, 7: 15595357, 8: 15595357, 9: 15595357},
        'Yield (tn per ha)': {0: 8.109, 1: 8.109, 2: 8.109, 3: 8.109, 4: 8.109, 5: 8.109, 6: 8.109, 7: 8.109, 8: 8.109, 9: 8.109}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I did this:

```
df['Stage'] = df['Stage'].astype('category')
sns.relplot(data=df, x='Z-Score CEI', y='Stage', col='Index', kind='line', ax=ax, facet_kws={'sharey': True})
```

However, I get this error:
    `raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'x'`

Ultimately, I want the x-axis on the plot to be narrow as I am expecting to have a large number of columns (~50)

Comment: Your code works for me without error, what version of seaborn are you using?

Comment: 0.12.2, your version?

Comment: 0.11.2, I don't think replot was changed in that tho

Comment: Do not use `ax=ax` in `.relplot`, which is a figure-level function that does not have `ax=`. Given the [mre], this issue is not reproducible in `seaborn v0.13.0`

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error with seaborn 0.12.2

The reason for this KeyError are the nan values in the respective `Z-Score CEI` column. (see e.g. [this open seaborn issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3351))

To get rid of this error, you could clean up the data before plotting it. A brute force way would be df = df.dropna(), but in your case, this produces empty plots for me, so a more sophisticated cleaning seems to be required here to both avoid this error and still generate meaningful plots.