# Exclude subplots without any data and left-align the rest in relplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, relplot

Related to this question: [Use relplot to plot a pandas dataframe leading to error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77442845/use-relplot-to-plot-a-pandas-dataframe-leading-to-error)

Data for reproducible example is here:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Index': ['TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN', 'TN10p', 'CSU', 'PRCPTOT', 'SDII', 'CWD', 'R99p', 'R99pTOT', 'TX', 'MIN'],
        'Stage': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28],
        'Z-Score CEI': [-0.688363146221944, 0.5773502691896258, -0.1132178081286216, -0.4278470185781525, 1.0564189237269357, -0.2085144140570746, -0.2085144140570747, 0.2094308186874662, 0.7196177629619716, 0.0, 0.2085144140570762, -1.3803992008056865, -1.3414801279616884, -0.898669162696764, -0.3015113445777637, -0.2953788838542738, 1.1753566728623484, 0.887285779752818, -0.7071067811865475, 0.2847473987257496, 0.1877402877114761, -0.14246249364941, 0.9686648999069224, -0.3015113445777636, -0.2734952011457535, 0.5888914135578924, -0.4488478006064821, -0.7745966692414834, 0.3052145041378634, 0.8197566686157259, 0.3377616284580471, 1.1832159566199232, -0.3015113445777637, -0.2952684241380082, -0.7971688059921156, 0.4479595231454734, -0.5805577953661853, 0.3015113445777642, -0.610500944190139, -0.7734588159553295, -0.5434722467562666, -0.2085144140570747, -0.2085144140570747, 0.8838570486142397, -0.7976091842744983, 2.213211486674006, 0.3779644730092272, -0.6900911175081499, -0.4856558012299846, -0.6044504143545613, -0.2085144140570746, -0.2085144140570747, 1.6498242899497324, 0.463638205246897, -0.064684622735315, 0.5488212999484522, -0.665392754456709, -1.096398502672124, 0.9387247898517332, -0.2085144140570747, -0.2085144140570748, 1.5486212537866115, 0.6776076459912243, -0.7973761651368712, 0.4773960376293314, 0.2611306759187019, -0.2450438178293888, 0.1097642599896903, -0.2085144140570746, -0.2085144140570747, 1.2468175442040146, 0.4912008775378222, -0.8071397220005339, 0.3015113445777636, -0.4051430868010012, -0.9843673918740764, 0.4231429298696365, -0.2085144140570746, -0.2182178902359924, 1.0617336112420042, 0.4221998839727844, -0.2267786838055363, 0.2847473987257496, 1.2708306299144654, 2.4058495687034616, -0.1042572070285372, 4.79583152331272, 4.79583152331272, -0.1758750648062869, 0.9614146130140746, -0.6493094697110509, 0.2847473987257496, -0.0566333001085325, 0.0970016157961683, -0.3380617018914065, -0.2085144140570746, -0.2132007163556104, 1.6462867435913509, 0.8920062635166146, -0.649519052838329, 0.2847473987257496, -0.5727902328114448, -0.385256843427376, 0.123403510468459, -0.2085144140570747, -0.2085144140570747, 0.7206954054604126, -0.0169294393471337, -0.1547646465068273, 0.3900382256192578, -0.91200685504817, -0.7643838011372592, -0.8553913029328061, -0.2085144140570746, -0.2132007163556104, 1.999517273479448, 0.2135313581345105, 0.3577708763999664, 0.2085144140570741, -0.5245759407883583, -0.3972170332271401, 0.1363988678940945, -0.2085144140570746, -0.2085144140570747, 2.180043023382912, 0.6949201395674811, -0.0345238339879863, 0.3872983346207417, -1.054383845470446, -0.7524909974608698, -0.79555728417573, -0.2085144140570747, -0.2085144140570747, 2.597515932302782, -0.0173575308522844, -0.7839294959021852, 0.5496481403962044, 0.3346732026206391, -0.1729151200242987, 0.8108848540793832, -0.2085144140570747, -0.2085144140570747, -0.1975075078549267, -0.1333012766349092, -0.7300956427599692, 0.3495310368212778, -0.9383516638143292, 0.3757624051611033, -0.9198662110078, -0.2085144140570747, -0.2085144140570747, 0.1077379509580834, -0.0391099277150297, -0.8006407690254357, 0.5226257719601375, 0.2650955994479978, -0.3323178678594628, 1.348187695720845, -0.2085144140570746, -0.2085144140570748, 0.6009413558916348, 0.455353435995126, -0.5933908290969269, 0.0, 0.1226864783178058, -0.0252747129054563, 0.8212299340934688, -0.2085144140570746, -0.2132007163556105, -0.8954835101738379, -1.1134420487718968],
        'Type': ['Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI', 'Cold', 'Heat', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Rain', 'Temperature', 'VI']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to plot the data; rows should be based on the column `Type`, cols should be based on the column `Index`, the x-axis should be `Z-Score CEI`, and the y-axis should be based on `Stage` column. Currently, I am using `relplot` to do this:

```py
df = df.groupby('Index').filter(lambda x: not x['Z-Score CEI'].isna().all())
df["Type"] = df["Type"].astype("category")
df["Index"] = df["Index"].astype("category")

df["Type"] = df["Type"].cat.remove_unused_categories()
df["Index"] = df["Index"].cat.remove_unused_categories()

g = sns.relplot(
    data=df,
    x='Z-Score CEI',
    y='Stage',
    col='Index',
    row='Type',
    facet_kws={'sharey': True, 'sharex': True},
    kind='line',
    legend=False,
)

for (i,j,k), data in g.facet_data():
    if data.empty:
        ax = g.facet_axis(i, j)
        ax.set_axis_off()
```

However, this leads to a plot where the empty plots are distorting the placement of the subplots with data. I want there to be no empty areas.

Current output looks like so:
[image: rder]

In the graphic above, I want to remove all the subplots which have no data. This will result in different rows having different number of subplots e.g. 1st row might have 5 subplots and 2nd row will have only 4 subplots etc.

I want each row to only have the same `Type`, not mix multiple `Type`s.

Comment: Define a single column with the cross of present col / row values and then use `col` / `col_wrap`. It would be easier to demonstrate with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution that is based on @mwaskom's suggestion in the comments. The basic idea is to create an auxiliary column where for each Type, existing Index values are labeled 0,1,2,... which will act as the column index in the FacetGrid. Then after plotting the `relplot`, remove all Axes without data and fix the title of the ones with data by replacing the column index by the "real" Index value.

```py
# label existing Type-Index pairs
col_idx = df.value_counts(['Type', 'Index']).groupby(level=0, observed=False).cumcount().astype(str)
# map the labels back to the dataframe
df1 = df.merge(col_idx.reset_index(name='column_loc'), on=['Type', 'Index'], how='left')

# plot replot
g = sns.relplot(
    data=df1,             # <--- new dataframe
    x='Z-Score CEI',
    y='Stage',
    col='column_loc',     # <--- column is by the newly created column
    row='Type',
    facet_kws={'sharey': True, 'sharex': True},
    kind='line',
    legend=False,
)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    if not ax.lines:
        g.fig.delaxes(ax) # remove empty subplots
    else:
        # fix the title
        typ, loc = (x.split(' = ')[1] for x in ax.get_title().split(' | '))
        idx, = col_idx[col_idx==loc].loc[typ].index
        ax.set_title(f"Type = {typ} | Index = {idx}")
```

[image: result]

I think for this particular task, matplotlib is very easy to use IMO. It's because both `Type` and `Index` columns are dtype Categorical, so by passing `observed=True` to pandas `groupby`, we can simply drop Index values that don't exist for each Type. Basically, we can use a nested groupby to create a sub-dataframe which can be fed into `lineplot`. However, because we need to manually plot each lineplot, it may be slow (maybe not since `relplot` is slow anyway).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
gby_obj = df.groupby('Type', observed=True)
nrows = gby_obj.ngroups
ncols = gby_obj['Index'].nunique().max()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, figsize=(20,20), sharey=True, sharex=True)
for i, (typ, g1) in enumerate(gby_obj):
    for j, (idx, g2) in enumerate(g1.groupby('Index', observed=True)):
        sns.lineplot(data=g2, x='Z-Score CEI', y='Stage', ax=axs[i,j])
        axs[i,j].set_title(f'Type = {typ} | Index = {idx}')
    for a in axs[i,j+1:]:
        fig.delaxes(a)
sns.despine(fig, top=True, right=True)
fig.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe if you could achieve want you want by using `relplot`.

What I would suggest, is to create `FacetGrid` and then for each rows adjust number of columns by deleting the most right plots if needed, then create `lineplot` for each `Type | Index`.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = df.groupby('Index').filter(lambda x: not x['Z-Score CEI'].isna().all())
df["Type"] = df["Type"].astype("category")
df["Index"] = df["Index"].astype("category")

df["Type"] = df["Type"].cat.remove_unused_categories()
df["Index"] = df["Index"].cat.remove_unused_categories()

# Get unique types
types = df['Type'].unique()
# Get unique indexes
indices = df['Index'].unique()

indices_len = len(indices)

# Create FaceGrid
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Index", row="Type")

row_number = 0
for t in types:
    
    # Filter for Type
    df_type = df[df['Type'] == t]
    # Determine the number of columns for this type
    num_cols = len(df_type['Index'].unique())
    
    # Remove plots that are not needed
    for i in range(indices_len - num_cols):
        ax = g.facet_axis(row_number, indices_len - i - 1)
        plt.delaxes(ax)
        
    
    col_number = 0
    for index in indices:
        # Filter data for each index
        df_index = df_type[df_type['Index'] == index]
        if not df_index.empty:
            # if dataframe not empty add lineplot
            ax = g.facet_axis(row_number, col_number)
            sns.lineplot(data=df_index, x='Z-Score CEI', y='Stage', ax=ax)
            ax.set_title(f"Type: {t} | Index: {index}")
            col_number += 1
    
    row_number += 1
```

Output plot:
[image]