# Use different colors for different parts of a line in seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Related to the accepted answer of this question: [Exclude subplots without any data and left-align the rest in relplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471818/exclude-subplots-without-any-data-and-left-align-the-rest-in-relplot)

Is there a way to use the seaborn lineplot such that values in certain ranges are painted using one color and other values in other colors. I want to use green to paint `Z-Score CEI` values between -1 and 1 and red to paint any `Z-Score CEI` values < -1 or > 1? Essentially the same line will have different color based on its value at that point. The x-axis will be the `Stage` values

Comment: What are trying to plot exactly? `Z-Score CEI` on y-axis and x-axis as index?

Comment: x-axis will be `Stage`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a function using the examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121773/is-it-possible-to-change-line-color-in-a-plot-if-exceeds-a-specific-range).

This treats the data as set of line segments and colors them individually based on condition

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm

def threshold_plot(ax, x, y, threshv, color, overcolor, undercolor):
    """
    Helper function to plot points above a threshold in a different color

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : Axes
        Axes to plot to
    x, y : array
        The x and y values

    threshv : float
        Plot using overcolor above this value

    color : color
        The color to use for the lower values

    overcolor: color
        The color to use for values over threshv

    undercolor: color
        The color to use for values under threshv

    """
    # f' < threshv undercolor, f' > threshv overcolor, and the rest color
    cmap = ListedColormap([undercolor, color, overcolor])
    norm = BoundaryNorm([np.min(y), -threshv, threshv, np.max(y)], cmap.N)

    # Create a set of line segments so that we can color them individually
    # This creates the points as a N x 1 x 2 array so that we can stack points
    # together easily to get the segments. The segments array for line collection
    # needs to be numlines x points per line x 2 (x and y)
    points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

    # Create the line collection object, setting the colormapping parameters.
    # Have to set the actual values used for colormapping separately.
    lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    lc.set_array(y)

    ax.add_collection(lc)
    ax.set_xlim(np.min(x), np.max(x))
    ax.set_ylim(np.min(y)*1.1, np.max(y)*1.1)
    return lc
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = df['Stage'].to_numpy()
y = df['Z-Score CEI'].to_numpy()

lc = threshold_plot(ax, x, y, 1, 'k', 'r')
ax.axhline(1, color='k', ls='--')
ax.axhline(-1, color='k', ls='--')
lc.set_linewidth(3)
```

Each line segment is generated from point A to point B and coloring them, but since point B might be below the threshold the coloring can go below the threshold lines too.

[image]

A simpler and neater solution might be to just highlight the points that are above threshold using scatter points:

```
plt.plot(df['Stage'], df['Z-Score CEI'])
data1 = df[df['Z-Score CEI'].abs() >= 1]
# plt.scatter(df['Stage'], df['Z-Score CEI'], c = 'blue')
plt.scatter(data1['Stage'], data1['Z-Score CEI'], c = 'red')

plt.axhline(1, c='black', ls='--')
plt.axhline(-1, c='black', ls='--')
```

[image]